# Download CSV file from database using Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, csv

I need to download data from two database tables (factory and factoryType) using the form below but it isn't working. I managed to get data only out of one table... Can somebody take a look?

```
Factory table:factoryId,factoryname
FactoryType table: factoryType,factoryTypeId
FactoryConf table: factoryID,factoryTypeId
```

We are using Hibernate for the database operations.

**Form**

```
<form:form id="FactoryUploadForm" method="post" modelAttribute="FactoryUploadForm" action="/submitUploadFactoryForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="ui-widget" width="100%>
<tr>
                                <td valign="top" colspan=3 height="40px">
                                    <div class="column span-15 highlight">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                      <h><a href="/download.do">Click here to download file</a></h>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="column span-2_5"><label for="filedata">Select CSV File:</label><span style="color: red">*</span></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="column span-4"><input class="span-5 ui-input" type="file" id="fileData" name="fileData" size="45" /></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="column span-2_5"><label for="uploadComment">Comment/Description:</label></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="column span-4"><input class="span-5 ui-input" type="text" maxlength="100" id="uploadComment" name="uploadComment" size="50" /></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td colspan=2>
                                    <div class="column " style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" "/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="javascript:resetUploadFactoryForm();"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


</table>
</form:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class NewFactoryUploadDownloadController {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(NewFactoryUploadDownloadController.class);  
    @Resource
    IInteropService interopService;
    @Resource
    FactoryUploadRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/download.do")
    public String downloadFactory(FactoryUploadForm form, Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try{
        logger.debug("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ "Backup" +".csv");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-csheck=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            pw = response.getWriter();
            // Get, Write and flush the data.
            pw.println("Factory Id,FactoryLegalName,FactoryShortName,FactoryType");

         List<Factory> factoryFromDB = Collections.emptyList();               
         factoryFromDB = Service.getfactories();
         logger.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

            for(Factory factory : factoryFromDB)
            {
                pw.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                            factory.getId(),
                            formatString(factory.getName()),
                            factory.getShortName()));
            }
            pw.flush();

        }catch (Exception ex){
           logger.error("Error while downloading companies",  ex);
           model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "Error while downloading companies");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String formatString(String str){
        if (str.contains(",")){       
            return "\""+str + "\"";
    }
        return "\""+str + "\"";
    }

 }
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FactoryConf", uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "factoryId" } )
})
public class FactoryConf {

    @Id
    long factoryId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "factoryId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Factory factory;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "factoryTypeId")
    FactoryType factoryType;

    public FactoryConf() {
        super();
    }

    public FactoryConf(long factoryId, FactoryType factoryType) {
        super();
        this.factoryType = factoryType;
        this.factoryId = factoryId;
    }

    public Factory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public void setFactory(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public FactoryType getFactoryType() {
        return factoryType;
    }

    public void setFactoryType(FactoryType factoryType) {
        this.factoryType = factoryType;
    }

    public long getFactoryId() {
        return factoryId;
    }

    public void setFactoryId(long factoryId) {
        this.factoryId = factoryId;
    }

    public FactoryType getFactoryTypeByFactoryID(long factoryId){
        return factoryType;
    }
}
```